# What is directory scr/main/scala-2.11 in sbt?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I understand what belongs into the directories

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/main/scala
```

of the sbt hierarchy, but when I build my project the directories

```
src/main/scala-2.11
src/test/scala-2.11
```

are created by IntelliJ. What is the reason? What are those good for and what am I supposed to put into them?